# Installing tensorflow Mac GPU pywrap Import error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@fabmilo/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-cuda-support-on-osx-fd27108e27e1#.i48zcx3ty) and I'm getting this error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

I've installed everything correctly but I haven't been able to import tensorflow. I have tried to reinstall protobuf and pip from source. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: That usually means it can't find `_pywrap_tensorflow.so`. Look at `sys.path` and make sure that the `.so` file is one of those files. More rarely, it means it found it, but during loading of the `.so` there was another dependency that failed. One way to catch those errors is to run under `strace -Ttf` (or `dtruss` on Mac) and look for `open` syscalls to see if all `.so` open failed with no such file

Comment: Any progress with fixing this? If _pywrap_tensorflow.so isn't in sys.path, how would you fix it?

Comment: with the recent changes with tensorflow pip install tensorflow-gpu works best